# Cannot read property 'Keyboard' of undefined Ionic issue

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngMessages', 'ngCordova', 'jett.ionic.filter.bar',
'ion-datetime-picker', 'angularMoment', 'ngCordova.plugins.progressIndicator', 'ionic-timepicker']) //, $httpProvider
.config(configBlock)
// .factory('MyHttpInterceptor', MyHttpInterceptor)
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

But I got

> "Cannot read property 'Keyboard' of undefined" error

once I run the command `ionic serve`. I have already added the plugin --> ionic-plugin-keyboard to my project. Can someone help me to find this issue?

Comment: Try reInstall cordova keyboard plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard.

Comment: Hi,I added that.So should I use this "Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar(value, successCallback);" ?

Comment: Same,Cannot read property 'Keyboard' of undefined.Is there any place I should define plugins which I use?

Comment: check this https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/902

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-keyboard-of-undefined/25455/3

Answer (score 1):

Fix Only for Android :

Use window.Keyboard instead of cordova.plugins.Keyboard

Your code should like this :

```
if (window.cordova && window.Keyboard) {
    window.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
```

In the doc, it's written that there is a method called Keyboard.hideFormAccessoryBar. It's true for iOS but on Android, the method is called Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar. You can check the js code in Keyboard.js file located under : file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js. Or you can use chrome://inspect/#devices to debug whats going on.

I hope this will fix your issue.